# Angular Interview Questions

Tags: angularjs

I am preparing for an upcoming job interview and am trying to brush up on my Angular knowledge. I've been looking for Angular interview questions and came across this [resource](https://www.interviewbit.com/angular-interview-questions/).

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out with some of the code questions. For example, there is one question that asks to explain the following code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <h1>{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
</script>
```

I think I understand the concepts here, but I'd love to get some more insight from someone who has experience with Angular.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly have you understood (and how, write it down) and what not? There are a lot "concepts" in that piece of code.

Comment: Please be aware that the code you provided is angular1 version. Angular2+ is different .

Comment: That is angularjs code but you are writing about angular. I changed your tag accordingly.

Comment: Another point if your interviewer is actually wanting to know about angularjs is that the framework has reached End of Life at the end of on December 31st, 2021 and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to clarify for you (but I think it's simple concepts on angularjs)

First, define **angular.module** with the name **myApp** *, module is the same container that includes everything needed for the angular app (controller, directive, service,...)*. On HTML call **ng-app="myApp"** *angular will find directive ng-app to run first*

Second define  **app.controller** with the name **myCtrl** , controller include directive **$scope** to save *data* and *function*

Third on HTML use **interpolation** e.g above **{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}** it will read the value of variables  **defined on controller**.  After running on the browser  will show: John Doe

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are declaring your entry point and adding an anonymous function onto the controller in the declared module to the output of the interpolated header.

Comment: Also this looks like it’s angularjs and you probably want a newer version of angular